# Building Boxplots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to reproduce a boxplot with some given data. One variable is Energy Consumption and the other one is number of republican voters or democrat voters. I'm trying to get a boxplot to compare the median energy consumption of republicans vs democrats, based on their voters and the energy consumption for each county. My data is in a data frame called master.

```
p <- ggplot(master)
boxdata2 <- rbind(data.frame(Change = master$Energy.Expenditures,
                             Votes = master$votes_dem,
                             Party = "Democratic",
                             color = "blue"),
                  data.frame(Change = master$Energy.Expenditures,
                             Votes = master$votes_gop,
                             Party = "Republican",
                             color = "red"))
boxdata2 <- na.omit(boxdata2)
p + geom_boxplot(data = boxdata2,
                 aes(x = Party, y = Change~Votes, fill = color))
```

However, I get this **error**:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (6222): x, y, fill

Any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT 1:
Here's what I am trying to build with the boxplot command:

```
data1<-(data.frame(Change=rep(master$Energy.Expenditures, 
times = master$votes_dem), Party="Democratic",color="blue"))
data2<-(data.frame(Change=rep(master$Energy.Expenditures,
times= master$votes_gop), Party="Republican",color="red"))
boxplot(c(data1[1],data2[1]))
```

I want to get this (see link, sorry but I don't have enough reputation to post images) but with ggplot to get the format I used before, however, given the total number of rows (60 million for each) R runs out of memory, which is why I tried what I mentioned above

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Wii.jpg

EDIT2:

I can build it using the summary stats from EDIT 1, but I want to know if there is a way to perform EDIT1 under ggplot.

Comment: Can you say what `Change` is? Do you want `facet_wrap(~Change)`?

Comment: You can't have a formula for your `y` value (`y=Change~Votes` is not allowed). What exactly do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I tried someting else but R couldn't allocate because of all the memory required. I tried using change as `Change=rep(master$Energy.Expenditures,times=master$votes_gop`. So, I have a count for each energy percentage, and then get the boxplot from this information. However, since there are 120 million voters, the dataset is too big and R runs out of memory, so I tried to make the percentages as a factor of the n number of voters with the ~ operator, but it does not work.

Comment: From your last comment, consider editing your post as you are attempting a calculation that you do not describe in text. Please delete above long comment and incorporate in your post. Specifically, describe what you want to run in boxplots.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to generate a simple boxplot in `ggplot2`, and compares it to `base` R code for generating the same boxplot. As already pointed out in one of the comments, although you use a formula (e.g., `Change~Votes` in your example) in the `base` R code, you don't do this in `ggplot2`; there you just specify the x and y variable.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

```
boxplot(hwy~class, data=mpg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
require(ggplot2)

# fake numeric data
dd <- function(){
  round(rnorm(10, 10, 2), 0)
}

# your dummy data
boxdata2 <- rbind(data.frame(Change = dd(),
                             Votes = dd(),
                             Party = "Democratic",
                             color = "blue"),
                  data.frame(Change =  dd(),
                             Votes =  dd(),
                             Party = "Republican",
                             color = "red"))

ggplot(boxdata2) +
    geom_boxplot(data = boxdata2, aes(x = Party, y = Change, color = color)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), labels = c("Democrat","Republican")) +
  facet_wrap(~Votes)
```

[image]